# Trying to install Azure Bot framework tools and getting error

Tags: node.js, .net, macos, npm, botframework

I am on mac, npm 6.14.4 and dotnet 3.1.300

I am getting the following install error and not able to install dispatch cli.

> ```
> Failed at the dotnet-2.1@2.1.1005 postinstall script.
> ```

I am following the instruction from [here](https://microsoft.github.io/botframework-solutions/virtual-assistant/tutorials/create-assistant/csharp/2-download-and-install/#download-and-install).